# array.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I keep getting this error
*escalationreport.js:62 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: results.map is not a function*

```
{escalated_by: "Osten Diniz", ticket_Number: "SHA-194414", escalation_reason: "Closing sale", date: "2020-03-31T16:25:30.000Z"}
```

This is console log in the browser level

I am trying to map these values to a table but fails with the above error

I found that data.map is only possible for arrays but don't know how to convert that json to array ({} to [])

Comment: This is not an array, it is an object.

Comment: Check Object.entries() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys()` or `Object.entries()` and then use `map`

```
Object.entries(yourObject).map((arr) => {
 // arr[0] will have the key and arr[1] will have the value of a key-value 
 // pair of yourObject.
 console.log(arr) 
})
```

Comment: is Object a keyword?

Comment: @OstenDiniz no, [it's the global Object constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Comment: @OstenDiniz No, it is not a keyword. A keyword is something like `return`.

Comment: @OstenDiniz you're right. I messed up in my head...

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = {escalated_by: "Osten Diniz", ticket_Number: "SHA-194414", 
escalation_reason: "Closing sale", date: "2020-03-31T16:25:30.000Z"};

 // one
var keys= Object.keys(result);
keys.map(v => {
  console.log("KEY  ========>",v);
});

// two
var entries= Object.entries(result);
entries.map(v => {
   console.log("KEY  ========>",v[0],"VALUE  ========>",v[1]);
});
```

Comment: `[result]` will just create an array with one element that is the result object. We can't use that to loop through the properties of an object.